# How can a normal map be masked through a stenci?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, masking

I have a mesh that i use as a ground in the game engine, I used multiple stenci layers to dispatch the textures, all tileable. It works well but for the normal channel, what i mean is that when I turn on normal influence for a texture, it appears on the other layers without taking the stencis into consideration, so that when each texture has its normal turned on, the effect piles up until the last layer. What I have managed to do is to create normal maps for every layers but the last (the path as you can see on the picture) but in doing so i'm loosing the ability to repeat my picture. Is there a way through this ? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the node system to use my normal maps in HD, instead of stenci I set up a series of color mix nodes. I needed to substract a geometry normal node via a vector math...don't ask me why. 
[image]